# Add Subscriber to Mailchimp list via Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to automate the addition of subscribers to a mailchimp mailing list using a google doc and google app script, which connects to the external mailchimp API. Whenever I try to test my script I receive a 'bad value' exception from StackDriver Log.

```
var payload = {
    "email_address": email,
    "status_if_new": "subscribed",
    "merge_fields": {
      FNAME: first_name,
      LNAME: last_name
    },
  };

  var headers = {
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "apikey " + API_KEY,
  };

  var data = {
    "method": "PUT",
    "muteHttpExceptions": false,
    "headers": headers,
    "payload": payload,
  };

  var json = Utilities.jsonStringify(data);
  
  //DEBUG
  Logger.log(json);
  Logger.log(endpoint);

  // call the Mailchimp API
  try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, json);

    if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
      // all good!
      Logger.log("Success");
      Logger.log(response);
    } else {
      Logger.log("Issues");
      Logger.log(response);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // handle the error here
    Logger.log("Error");
    Logger.log(err);
  }
```

```
Sep 5, 2020, 1:02:53 PM Info Exception: Bad value
```

Upon further investigation with curl, I found that manually sending a request with the same payload and headers gave this response.

```sh
curl -X PUT 'https://{server}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{my_list}/members/{member_hash}' 
         -H {"Authorization":"apikey {API_KEY}","contentType":"application/json"} 
         -d '{"email_address":"test@test.com","status_if_new":"subscribed","merge_fields":{"LNAME":"test","FNAME":"test"}},"muteHttpExceptions":false}'
```

```json
"errors":[{"field":"email_address","message":"This value should not be blank."}]
```

Why does the API not recognize the email I am providing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that you're passing a JSON string as the `params` argument where an object is expected in [`UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)). Instead of stringifying all of `data`, you only need to stringify the payload. (Note the example linked in the Apps Script documentation.)

I suspect you'll also face an issue with `Utilities.jsonStringify()` as it's [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#jsonStringify(Object)). Use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) instead.

I also moved contentType out of `headers` and into `data`, as this is how it's specified in the `fetch()` method, but it actually has no impact on your application.

```
var payload = {
  "email_address": email,
  "status_if_new": "subscribed",
  "merge_fields": {
    FNAME: first_name,
    LNAME: last_name
  },
};

var headers = {
  "Authorization": "apiKey " + API_KEY
};

var data = {
  "method": "PUT",
  "muteHttpExceptions": false,
  "headers": headers,
  "contentType": "application/json",
  "payload": JSON.stringify(payload) // The payload should be stringified
};

//DEBUG
Logger.log(endpoint);

// call the Mailchimp API
try {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, data); // pass in data, not json

  if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
    // all good!
    Logger.log("Success");
    Logger.log(response);
  } else {
    Logger.log("Issues");
    Logger.log(response);
  }
} catch (err) {
  // handle the error here
  Logger.log("Error");
  Logger.log(err);
}
```

If you're *only* going to be adding subscribers, then I'd recommend you use the [add members to list](https://mailchimp.com/developer/api/marketing/list-members/add-member-to-list/) endpoint. It's just a bit more straightforward and doesn't require that you generate a member hash.